# Как зациклить таймер обратного отсчета?

Tags: таймер, счетчики, javascript

Имеется такой код

```
function CountdownTimer(elm,tl,mes){
 this.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
}
CountdownTimer.prototype={
 initialize:function(elm,tl,mes) {
 this.elem = document.getElementById(elm);
 this.tl = tl;
 this.mes = mes;
},countDown:function(){
var timer='';
var today=new Date();
var day=Math.floor((this.tl-today)/(24*60*60*1000));
var hour=Math.floor(((this.tl-today)%(24*60*60*1000))/(60*60*1000));
var min=Math.floor(((this.tl-today)%(24*60*60*1000))/(60*1000))%60;
var sec=Math.floor(((this.tl-today)%(24*60*60*1000))/1000)%60%60;
var me=this;

if( ( this.tl - today ) > 0 ){
timer += '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">DAYS</div><span class="number day">'+day+'</span></span>';
timer += '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">HOURS</div><span class="number hour">'+hour+'</span></span>';
timer += '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">MINS</div><span class="number min">'+this.addZero(min)+'</span></span><span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">SECS</div><span class="number sec">'+this.addZero(sec)+'</span></span>';
this.elem.innerHTML = timer;
tid = setTimeout( function(){me.countDown();},10 );
}else{
this.elem.innerHTML = this.mes;
return;
}
},addZero:function(num){ return ('0'+num).slice(-2); }
}
function CDT(){

// Set countdown limit year mounth date
var tl = new Date('2014/03/30 00:00:00');

// You can add time's up message here
var timer = new CountdownTimer('CDT',tl,'<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><span class="number end">Time is up!      </span></span>');
 timer.countDown();
}
window.onload=function(){
 CDT();
}
```

как зациклить его на определенном времени, например на 00 дней 18 часов 00 минут 00 сек, и чтобы по прошествию этого времени происходил ресет и все начиналось заново.

Comment: @glebkachalkin, на будущее: <pre>, к сожалению, отображается только в превью, а в самом вопросе появится как обычный текст? форматирование кода осуществляется с помощью кнопки `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил ошибку, можно посмотреть целиком [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/jUWyJ/)

Comment: счетчик дней бешенно побежал вверх..

Comment: @glebkachalkin, допустил тупейшую ошибку, теперь исправил.

Comment: Спасибо больше, все заработало корректно! Время как я понимаю выставлено на 24 часа до 17:09 каждого следующего дня, верно?

Comment: @glebkachalkin, оно прибавляет двадцать четыре часа, если меньше текущего, до тех пор, пока не станет больше. так что **в общем** ответ будет да.